# Selecting the second most recent text message with Java on Android

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

Is it possible to select the second message in a conversation using Java on the Android platform?

```
Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
cur.moveToNext();

String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
String add = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));

if (protocol == null)
 out = ""+body;
else
 out = ""+body;
```

I want to query the inbox and select the second most recent text message.
What would be the best way to do this with the code above? Is it possible to refine the query that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);

```
cur.moveToNext();
cur.moveToNext();
```

call moveToNext() another time. That points your cursor to second message in the query results.

Add NullPointer checks otherwise, if second message is not there you will end up NullPointerException.

Comment: That works. Thank you. What a simple solution. I was over complicating things.